# How to plot equation

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

How to plot these equations please? The output is empty - there are only axes but no line

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


r = 50
a = 5
n = 20
t = 5
x = (r + a * np.sin(n * t * 360 )) * np.cos (t * 360 )
y = (r + a * np.sin(n * t * 360 )) * np.sin (t * 360 )


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are currently just calculating single values for `x` and `y`:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> r, a, n, t = 50, 5, 20, 5
>>> x = (r + a * np.sin(n * t * 360 )) * np.cos (t * 360 )
>>> y = (r + a * np.sin(n * t * 360 )) * np.sin (t * 360 )
>>> print(x, y)
-47.22961311822641 6.299155241288046
```

This means there is no line for matplotlib to plot.

To plot a line, you have to pass two or more points for matplotlib to draw lines between.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

t = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)  # create an array of 100 points between 0 and 2*pi
x = np.sin(2*t)
y = np.cos(t)

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Or in your case:

```py
t = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 1000) 
# removed the factor *360 as numpy's sin/cos works with radians by default
x = (r + a * np.sin(n * t)) * np.cos(t) 
y = (r + a * np.sin(n * t)) * np.sin(t) 
plt.plot(x, y) 
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting image]

Comment: Thank you very much and how to compute the area of this shape?

Comment: @Archie I have no idea, and it sounds more like a mathematics question than a programming question

Answer (score 2):

You are evaluating the function just at `t=5`. You should give a range of values to evaluate. If you change `t` variable to, for example

`t= np.array([0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1])`

you will see a graph. But it is up to you to define the range and the step for your needs